# How to avoid `postgresql duplicate key violates unique constraint` erorr from showing up?

Tags: postgresql

My environment is basically an API backed by Postgres. We ran into a unique situation where one of the user came back saying that they are running into following error:

> postgresql duplicate key violates unique constraint

After some search, I found that solution is to follow instructions that are mentioned here:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4448340/postgresql-duplicate-key-violates-unique-constraint

It was pretty helpful and I was able to reset the `identity sequence` to a higher number and it seems to work all fine. However, what I was more interested into was how to avoid this error from happening altogether? In our case this happened because of of the engineer on the team performed multiple `bulk-inserts` and that threw the identity sequence out of sync.

The reason for this question is because, while I understand from this article

https://hcmc.uvic.ca/blogs/index.php/how_to_fix_postgresql_error_duplicate_ke?blog=22

that it is by design. Which kind of confuses me. The question in my head is that how/why is it safe to assume from postgress side that bulk -inserts are not that usual? More important question is that is there any setting in postgress that I can turn on/off to make sure that the identity sequence does not go out of sync every time a bulk-insert is performed?

Comment: If you have a unique constraint, you cannot have duplicate values.  You might revise the question to describe what you're doing that's creating duplicate values.

Comment: Well, as mentioned below, it is an identity column and we are not inserting any duplicate values. What is going on is that after bulk insert, Postgres loses its track on what was the list sequence(identity generated). So for example it had 200 values in db, and then we bulk-insert 100 values then instead of next value being 301, it tries to generate 201 and that causes the conflict.

Comment: Show us the CREATE TABLE design, the statements you use for the bulk inserts and the version of Postgres. Are you inserting values into the identity columns?

Comment: "*how to avoid this error from happening altogether*" - use an `identity` column with `generated always` then no developer can accidentally override the generation of values in the database.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you do a bulk insert, you need to do it competently.  Why would the engineer assume it is safe to make up his own external identifiers when he knows the database is in charge of making those?

You can still do a bulk insert while not specifying the identity column, relying on system to do it for you (correctly).